# SQL Server Pivot single column values by multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP (
    DATE DATETIME
    ,category VARCHAR(3)
    ,amount MONEY
    ,NAMES VARCHAR(5)
    )

INSERT INTO TEMP
VALUES (
    '1/1/2012'
    ,'ABC'
    ,1000.00
    ,'john'
    )

INSERT INTO TEMP
VALUES (
    '2/1/2012'
    ,'DEF'
    ,500.00
    ,'amy'
    )

INSERT INTO TEMP
VALUES (
    '2/1/2012'
    ,'GHI'
    ,800.00
    ,'blue'
    )

INSERT INTO TEMP
VALUES (
    '2/10/2012'
    ,'DEF'
    ,700.00
    ,'ivy'
    )

INSERT INTO TEMP
VALUES (
    '3/1/2012'
    ,'ABC'
    ,1100.00
    ,'mark'
    )

DECLARE @cols1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@cols2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols1 = STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.category)
            FROM TEMP c
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
SET @cols2 = STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.NAMES)
            FROM TEMP c
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
--select @cols
SET @query = 'SELECT date, ' + @cols1 + @cols2 + ' from

            (

                select date

                    , amount

                    , category

                                    , names

                from temp

           ) x

            pivot

            (

                 max(amount)

                for category in (' + @cols1 + ')

            ) p

                      pivot

            (

                 max(amount)

                for names in (' + @cols2 + ')

            ) p

              '

EXEC (@query)
```

Drop table temp

Below is the result I'm trying to get but I get an error Invalid column name 'amount'

```
     ABC         DEF    GHI     John    Amy    Blue     Ivy     Mark
1/1/2012    1000    NULL    NULL    1000    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2/1/2012    NULL    500     NULL    NULL    500     NULL    NULL    NULL
2/1/2012    NULL    NULL    800     NULL    NULL    800     NULL    NULL
2/10/2012   NULL    700     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    700     NULL
3/1/2012    1100    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1100
```

Comment: John, Amy, Blue, Ivy, Mark are not the categories so it will not come as column. You need to pivot twice for this and join based on the date.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query.

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP (
    DATE DATETIME
    ,category VARCHAR(3)
    ,amount MONEY
    ,NAMES VARCHAR(5)
    )

INSERT INTO TEMP
VALUES (
    '1/1/2012'
    ,'ABC'
    ,1000.00
    ,'john'
    )

INSERT INTO TEMP
VALUES (
    '2/1/2012'
    ,'DEF'
    ,500.00
    ,'amy'
    )

INSERT INTO TEMP
VALUES (
    '2/1/2012'
    ,'GHI'
    ,800.00
    ,'blue'
    )

INSERT INTO TEMP
VALUES (
    '2/10/2012'
    ,'DEF'
    ,700.00
    ,'ivy'
    )

INSERT INTO TEMP
VALUES (
    '3/1/2012'
    ,'ABC'
    ,1100.00
    ,'mark'
    )

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.category) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT date, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select date
                    , amount
                    , category
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(amount)
                for category in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use pivot like that, you need to pivot the data separately.

A quick way to get what you want would be:

```
WITH Table1 AS
(
SELECT date, [ABC],[DEF],[GHI] 
from
(

                select date

                    , amount

                    , category

                   , names

                from temp

           ) AS x

            pivot

            (

                MAX(Amount)

                for category in ([ABC],[DEF],[GHI])

            ) AS A
)
,Table2 AS
(

SELECT date, [amy],[blue],[ivy],[john],[mark] 
from
(

                select date

                    , amount

                    , category

                   , names

                from temp

           ) AS x

            pivot

            (
                 max(amount)

                for names in ([amy],[blue],[ivy],[john],[mark])

            ) AS B
)
SELECT *
FROM Table1 A
INNER JOIN Table2 B on A.date = B.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hope you got your result from this query.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (DATE DATETIME,category VARCHAR(3),amount MONEY,NAMES VARCHAR(5))

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('3/1/2012','ABC',1100.00,'mark')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('1/1/2012','ABC',1000.00,'john')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('2/10/2012','DEF',700.00,'ivy')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('2/1/2012','DEF',500.00,'amy')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('2/1/2012','GHI',800.00,'blue')

select * into #Category from (-----CREATE PIVOT BASED ON CATEGORY FROM #TEMP TABLE AND INSERT DATA INTO #CATEGORY TABLE
select * from #TEMP
) as t1
pivot (sum(amount) for Category IN ([ABC],[DEF],[GHI])) AS CategoryAmount

select * into #Names from (-----CREATE PIVOT BASED ON NAMES FROM #TEMP TABLE AND INSERT DATA INTO #Names TABLE
select * from #TEMP
) as t1
pivot (sum(amount) for names IN ([amy],[blue],[ivy],[john],[mark])) AS CategoryAmount

--HERE IS YOUR FINAL QUERY WHERE YOU GOT YOUR RESULT AS PER YOUR REQUIREMENT 
select c.DATE,SUM(c.ABC) ABC,SUM(c.DEF) DEF,SUM(c.GHI) GHI,SUM(n.John) JOHN,SUM(n.Amy) AMY,SUM(n.Blue) BLUE,SUM(n.Ivy) IVY,SUM(n.Mark) MARK from #Category C
inner join #Names n on c.DATE = n.DATE
GROUP BY C.DATE
drop table #TEMP,#Category,#Names
```